# how can i bind an object to a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My code is

```
public Emp GetEmpByEmpno(int empno)
{
    using (con)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = constr;
            con.Open();
        }
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_emp_GetempByEmpno";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eno",empno);
        dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Emp obj=null;

        while(dr.Read())
        {
            obj=new Emp();
            obj.Empno=int.Parse(dr["Empno"].ToString());
            obj.Ename=dr["Ename"].ToString();
            obj.Sal=dr["Sal"].ToString();
            obj.Deptno=int.Parse(dr["Deptno"].ToString());

        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Here I fetch the record based on employee number, whenever i pass empno in textbox search button onClick, the respective employee should display in grid view. How can i bind the object to grid view?

```
Employee obj=EmpDeptBus.GetEmployeeByEmpno(int.Parse(txtEmpno.Text));            
gvemp.DataSource = c;
gvemp.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just say

```
gvemp.DataSource = obj;
```

That's really all you need to do to bind the object.
Also, change your

```
while(dr.Read())
```

to

```
if(dr.Read())
```

You're only expecting one record so only fetch one. Also put your return obj outside your using to make sure everything is properly disposed before you return to the calling function.

Try making sure that txtEmpno.Text holds an int value before you attempt to pass it to this method or it will blow up. Never, ever trust user input. You could do something like:

```
int empNo = 0;
if(int.TryParse(txtEmpNo.Text.Trim(), out empNo)
{
 //   then call the function and bind your grid using the empNo as the 
 // variable holding the employee number.
}
else
{
  // otherwise handle the fact that the user entered a non-numeric.
}
```